# How to reduce the Image size?

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing

```
loc =d_path+"\\a"+m+"a"+".jpg"; 
Image image = Image.getInstance (loc);
```

I want to reduce image width.  Could anyone help me out for the same?

Comment: how about reading _some_ type of documentation/tutorial/textbook first? F.i. at least skim over the methods supplied by the class you want to use?

Answer (score 3):

Image has method

```
public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)
```

Comment: how to give image url, in this method.

Comment: @jcrshankar: I do not mean to sound rude! You should either have a look at object oriented programming or think before you post. (Read this comment in the nicest possible way :-))

Comment: @jcrshankar you just call this method on the existing Image object